# Is it possible to audit changes to an oracle schema?

Tags: database, oracle

I am developing a product which uses an Oracle database (11g). The product will most likely have to be customised for each client - this may involve changing PLSQL functions slightly or modifying a view for instance. My question is: is there any way of automatically keeping a record of structural changes like this, and perhaps saving it to a table for future reference? Or will it have to be a more manual process e.g just remembering to insert a row into a log table describing any changes that have been made?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into "editions". They were introduced with 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about DDL commands, those can be tracked with DDL triggers. Create DDL trigger which inserts to some audit table.

More info:

http://psoug.org/reference/ddl_trigger.html

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ddl_triggers.htm